# "Debug assertion failed!" in release mode when calling mser->detectRegions from OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

If i run my application in x64 debug mode everything is fine. If i switch to release mode i get an error in line `mser->detectRegions(...);`.

Before `mser->detectRegions(...);` I load the image and convert it into a grayscale image, so i think it is not a general openCV issue or debug/release libraries issue.

[image]

```
std::vector< std::vector< cv::Point> > contours; 
std::vector< cv::Rect> boxes;  
cv::Ptr< cv::MSER> mser = cv::MSER::create(1, 500, 14400, 0.25 , 0.2, 200, 5, 0.003, 5); 
mser->detectRegions(greyMat, contours, boxes);
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Opencv 3.

Comment: As far as I see from this message, your program is still linked with debug version of vc++ library

Comment: Thanks, that was right. I liked "all configurations" against debug and release libraries. As explanation: In properties choose "debug configurations" and linked debug libs and then i choose "release configurations" and link release libs of opencv.